# Initializing a char * const array with data that is not known at compile time

Tags: c, arrays, char, constants

How do I initialize a char * const array with entries that are not literal? The entries are coming from standard input. I tried

```
char * const args[2] = (char * const *)calloc(2,1025);
sscanf(command,"%s %s ",args[0],args[1]);
/*args will be used later*/
```

and got "invalid initializer" if the cast wasn't there and "cast specifies array type" if the cast was there. And if I avoided calloc altogether, then both entries of args ended up being null. It seems like no matter what I do, an array of type char * const cannot be filled with values after it is declared.

Edit: Here is my next attempt

```
char **args = (char **)calloc(1025,3);
/*Section A start*/
strcpy(args[0],(char*)"the");
strcpy(args[1],(char*)"thethe");
/*Section A end*/
sscanf(command,"%s %s ",args[0],args[1]);
```

The conundrum that ails is code block is as follows. If I don't include section A, then args[0], args[1] are incorrectly null after the sscanf (apparently, sscanf does not work well with null variables). If I do include section A, I get a segfault on section A. So it seems I am flummoxed no matter which way I turn. Perhaps there is an alternative, some section B that gives args[0], args[1] throwaway values so that they can be in a non-null state when sscanf appears on the scene.

Comment: You are correct, it is const for a reason meaning it should not be modified and probably initialized through char * const args[2] = { 'a', 'b' };

Comment: @OmidCompSCI `'a'` is a character, while `"a"` can decay to a pointer to characters.

Comment: Well, while everything said here is true, I am left wondering why you want to do this?  What is your goal?  I'm guessing there is a better way to do what you want, but I'd need to understand what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: @FrankMerrow execvp requires the exact type char * const[]. Later on in my code I will call execvp(args[0],args).

Comment: @Displayname An `const` array of type X is not the same as a pointer to `const` pointers to values of X type.

Comment: @ThomasJager I got "cast specifies array type when trying char * const[]", which is why the 2nd asterisk was there. "char * const" and "char *" are both invalid. The array has to be of type char * const[] at some point, so if it doesn't start that way it has to be casted. But all of our attempts at casting have failed.

Comment: Read your type declaration. It says: constant array of 2 pointers to char. That is, you need to initialize it as an array, with 2 pointers. `const` is probably unnecessary but should be harmless if the variable is local.

Comment: Also reread `execvp` documentation. Last `args` entry must be NULL which means “end of arguments.” So your array needs to be longer by one than the argument list.

Comment: @numzero Good catch. Arrays of strings are not automatically terminated like arrays of chars are. I have posted a second attempt taking your suggestions into account. I am disappointed to learn that the only way to determine execvp can accept char ** is to know that char ** and char * const[] are treated equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last remaining fix is to replace section A with section B seen here:

```
char **args = (char **)calloc(1025,3);
/*Section B start*/
args[0] = (char*)malloc(1025);
args[1] = (char*)malloc(1025);
/*Section B end*/
sscanf(command,"%s %s ",args[0],args[1]);
```

Comment: It's still suspicious that `sizeof(char*)` is nowhere in the first `calloc`.

Comment: It should work as `calloc` zero-initializes memory. But you should use `calloc(3, sizeof(char*))` instead as you allocate an array of 3 char pointers only. Also unless you know `command` is not longer than 1024, limiting length in `sscanf` like `"%1024s %1024s "` is necessary to prevent possible buffer overflow.